# Update datetime column by a condition in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

| id | order_date | delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-23 | 2023-01-26 |
| 2 | 2023-05-21 | 2023-05-29 |
| 3 | 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-01 |
| 4 | 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-20 |
| 5 | 2023-08-21 | 2023-07-21 |

The rows 3 and 5 the delivery date is less than order date. So in these cases I will assume the delivery_date = order_date.

So I create the following query:

```
SELECT*,(case delivery_date<order_date then delivery_date = order_date else delivery_date=delivery_date end) as delivery_date_is_assumed
from table
```

The query above isn't working. I need the following output:

| id | order_date | delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-23 | 2023-01-26 |
| 2 | 2023-05-21 | 2023-05-29 |
| 3 | 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-03 |
| 4 | 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-20 |
| 5 | 2023-08-21 | 2023-08-21 |

Comment: Please tag only a **single** rdbms... I've removed the tag spam

Comment: ok thank you I will pay more attention in the next

Comment: I suggest adding the correct tag now so that the right experts can assist you.

Comment: "*The query above isn't working*" In what way? In addition to tagging the specific RDBMS you're using as @DaleK mentioned, please also include what you *expected* and what *actually* happened with this query. See [ask]

Comment: I having facing some issues to add fours columns in a table here. One moment I will do it

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Perhaps `greatest()` is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues.

The basic case syntax is this.

```
 CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

You're missing the first `when`.

You're not assigning to a column, simply give the value you want.

```
SELECT
  id, order_date
  case
    when delivery_date<order_date then order_date 
    else delivery_date
  end as delivery_date
from table
```

See [w3schools SQL Case Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)